# Wine requires a 3G/1G user/kernel memory split on Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wine

I'm playing with Wine on Raspbian Jessie. I just installed from source but executing wine returns:

```
Warning: memory above 0x80000000 doesn't seem to be accessible.
Wine requires a 3G/1G user/kernel memory split to work properly.
wine: failed to map the shared user data: c0000018
```

From [here](http://forum.eltechs.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=105), it seems recompiling the kernel with 3G/1G memory might help.

Since I've never did kernel compilation I would like some more motivation in order to go that way. May someone confirm the kernel compilation approach works well? Or perhaps suggest another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Exagear is shipped with a special build of wine that supports 2g/2g memory split. You should use only this build of wine, not the one from apt-get.